# Navigate between states with <a> </a> tag on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

How to navigate between states defined by `$stateProvider` on click of `<a> </a>` tag

Here's is my state..

```
    $stateProvider

    //region page States
    .state('page1', {
        url: "/pg1",
        templateUrl: 'page1.html',
        controller: 'page1Ctrl'
    })

    .state('page2', {
        url: '/pg2',
        templateUrl: 'page2.html',
        controller: 'page2Ctrl'
    })

    .state('page3', {
        url: '/pg3',
        templateUrl: 'page3.html',
        controller: 'page3Ctrl'
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To navigate between states you use the `ui-sref` attribute.

```
<a ui-sref="page2">Go to Page 2</a>
```

See doc here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

Comment: I need to use anchor tag to change the states.Is it possible?